# how to change a pose lib using script

Tags: scripting, rigging

I want to make a button that changes the active poselib to another one from the list, a specific one. I look in the console and can't see any operator. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, now to setting the pose lib

Simple operator that takes the name of the poselib (action) you want to make active, and sets it on the active object

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Change the Pose Lib"""
    bl_idname = "object.set_pose_lib"
    bl_label = "Set Pose Lib"
    name = StringProperty(options={'SKIP_SAVE'})

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        action = bpy.data.actions.get(self.name)
        if action:
            context.object.pose_library = action
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Example of usage

```
import bpy

def draw_button(self, context):        
    # change to a pose named "Pose"
    poselib = context.object.pose_library
    name = "PoseLib"
    op = self.layout.operator("object.set_pose_lib", text=name)
    op.name = name

bpy.types.DATA_PT_pose_library.append(draw_button)
```

Comment: I was talking about changing the active pose library not the pose_markers. sorry.

Comment: @nexxio amended answer to changing poselib, rather than markers.