# How to set active Pose Library selection from Python (for running ops)

Tags: python, rigging, pose-mode

(I also asked this on Blender Artists)

I’m trying to run:

```
bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose(pose_index=index)
```

For some reason I can’t seem to be able to find way to set active pose action to be able to run this.

I’ve found how to get access to current action (I think):

```
context.object.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.get(sel)
```

But it isn’t the same thing. Doing this does work for selecting action, it sets current action in Dope sheet BUT it doesn’t set it in Properties window’s Pose panel… rendering it useless.

I would need to be able to set the actual Properties window Pose Library panel selection.

If I run ops code with incorrect Pose Window selection, it just fails …but if I change target pose library manually, it works.

One would think that if ops exists, there has to be a way to also select which one of Pose Libraries to target.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Consider using `context.object.pose_library = action`  to set the pose library, and `obj.pose_library.pose_markers.active_index = pose_index` to set active marker (ie the `pose_index` in apply pose) `Related  (possible duplicate q/a)  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58595/how-to-change-a-pose-lib-using-script

Comment: Thanks. I did do several searches before asking, for example "python set pose library" doesn't find thread you linked. I find StackExchange search to be not so good. Will bookmark that thread too.

Comment: Agreed re searching on this site, can be very hit and miss.  Putting "[python]" in search term looks for questions tagged python.  Google site search , eg "site:blender.stackexchange.com python [search words]".  is often more productive.  Will close as dupe.